# Adding a fixed value to an existing function

Tags: wordpress, time, sum

I need to adjust the code below that displays a simplre Time to a "Start time - End Time", example: "12:00" should be "12:00- 14:00". Just adding 2 hours more to the first time.

Original Code:

```
foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
        $block_html .= '<li class="block" data-block="' . esc_attr( date( 'Hi', $block ) ) . '"><a href="#" data-value="' . date( 'G:i', $block ) . '">' . date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ), $block ) . '</a></li>';
    }

    return $block_html;
```

Should be something like:

```
foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
        $block_html .= '<li class="block" data-block="' . esc_attr( date( 'Hi', $block ) ) . '"><a href="#" data-value="' . date( 'G:i', $block ) . '">' . date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ), $block ) . ' - ' . /* HERE GOES THE END TIME*/ . '</a></li>';
    }

    return $block_html;
```

Thank you for any incoming help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, your `$block` contains a unix timestamp.
If yes, try this:

```
echo date( 'H:i', $block ) ." - " . date( 'H:i', $block + (60*60*2) );
```

You can use the [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function too.

Comment: Fantastic Lolka Bolka, it worked perfectly, thanx a lot for the very quick answer!

Comment: You are welcome. If you pleased with my answer, please accept it by clicking on the tick.